# The term 'vocal fry': where does it come from?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, american-english

On a recent Language Log posting [Vocal fry: "creeping in" or "still here"?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3626), Mark Liberman discusses an (also) recent article about the phenomenon of 'vocal fry' and shows how it has been around for quite awhile in the US (lots of references in that blog post).

I personally had never heard of this term, have never heard anybody talk about this phenomenon, have never heard anybody talk in the described manner, and frankly can't hear anything special in those utterances even where pointed out.

But my sound-blindness is not the issue. What I'd like to know is where the term 'vocal fry' comes from. **Who coined it or where did people start using it?** Presumably it is metaphorical (a 'frying' sound?). The blog posting doesn't address that, and wading through the references hasn't turned up anything yet.

Comment: I hadn't ever heard the term either (not surprising; I'm not a phonetician like Mark). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register) identifies and describes the sounds, but says nothing about what metaphor _fry_ refers to: frying sounds, spawn or young fish, effects of overheating, ... Could be lots of things, but since it's an auditory perception phenomenon, my guess would be the sound of bacon frying.

Comment: [Fry:](http://www.uiowa.edu/~shcvoice/glossary.html) A low-pitched vocal quality so called because the sound is similar to food cooking in a hot frying pan. It is characterized by intermittent "pops" of sound and produced by the vocal folds opening and closing irregularly and unrhythmically.

Comment: Both men and women tend to think a deeper voice is "sexier". Frying gives something of the illusion of that, and generally adds "character" to a voice if not overdone.

Comment: Have heard the girls _fryin'_, but had no idea it was a phenom with a name. Hmmm. I don't know. Maybe _vocal dying_ would be a better name. It sounds old and feeble.

Comment: Don't know, but wondering if it came from the same roots as "friable soil," that is, crumbly. Still checking, haven't found it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly right, it's because it's supposed to sound like the popping or sizzling of bacon frying.

the term was first used in ["Dynamic Variations of the Vibratory Pattern in the Normal Larynx" by Paul Moore and Hans Von Leden](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Dynamic%20Variations%20of%20the%20Vibratory%20Pattern%20in%20the%20Normal%20Larynx%3a%20by%20Paul%20Moore%20and%20Hans%20Von%20Leden&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=ws) in 1959 as far as I can find.

Comment: Well, it's used [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AN39JF0rNaUC&pg=PA2&dq=%22vocal+fry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QZj_TuuHBI-0hAeUvMjHCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22vocal%20fry%22&f=false) in 1931 - admittedly of apes, not Anglophones. And [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OL5rAAAAMAAJ&q=%22vocal+fry%22&dq=%22vocal+fry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9Zj_ToGjM5CLhQfxg6y5AQ&redir_esc=y) in 1949, in a "clinical" context. Not really the kind of expression that needs a "first use" - as you say, the imagery is pretty transparent, even if must of us have never heard of it!

Comment: Mark, @Fumble: the imagery, since I don't hear the phenomenon, fails for me. I find it hard to picture.

Comment: Mark, @Fumble: those source links would be great as an official answer, but they don't link to any actual viewable text for me. Can you give some small quotations of the original?

Comment: @Mitch: Oh - they work for me. I'm probably registered for Google Books, so you should try that if you're not already. But I now see that on the second link I had to click "search" on the first page, to get the actual text "vocal fry". I don't know why it did that. Also note the link in my question comment, defining how it's physically produced, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: your linked "[1931](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AN39JF0rNaUC&pg=PA2&dq=%22vocal+fry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QZj_TuuHBI-0hAeUvMjHCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22vocal%20fry%22&f=false)" references another 1957 paper on the same page, and the previous page gives a 1962 date for itself; 1931 was the date of the other paper published with it. The linked "[1949](http://bit.ly/VfW233)" is probably really [1965](http://bit.ly/UslX8a).

Comment: @Hugo: Good catch! You're definitely right about the first link, and probably the second too. But the main point is it's a transparent reference to frying bacon, etc., as Mark says here. In this case, explaining *how* the metaphor works seems far more important than finding a "first use".

Comment: Linking to Google Books and Scholar seems to depend both on registering/signing in, and also on nationality/location (or at least I've seen messages about something being restricted "in your country"). It's very useful to refer to, and it can be hard to cut and paste text if you want to quote it, but always helpful if someone takes the trouble to copy.

Answer (score 2):

I have antedated "glottal fry" to 1942, in an article by Henry Moser in the Journal of Speech Disorders. As I wrote in this article:

> Moser was able to guide the man to a normal voice by means of
> the 'glottal fry' attack. It is a method I have used with considerable
> success and one which I do not believe is well known. It is very easy to
> demonstrate but extremely difficult to describe. You may recognize it as
> the sound produced by many youngsters in imitating a motorboat but to me it
> more nearly resembles the sound of vigorously popping corn.

I also note in the article that the first attestation of "vocal fry" that I found was in the book *Voice and Articulation*, published in 1958, by Charles van Riper. This is earlier than the 1959 date in an earlier comment by one year. As for the 1949 date in another earlier comment, as best I can tell, this book was published in the 1960s, but I can't view the title page close enough to see.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about this in 2009. It's mostly heard with very young women and girls. I believe it's called vocal fry, because the voice sounds as if it's been fried and has become raspy. Young girls sound bitter and cynical when they growl at the end of a sentence.

It very likely began with the Gen X mothers of the Millennias.  This generation is scornful of the values of their Baby Boomer parents who left them a legacy of fractured families and federal deficits.  Dad was promised a gold watch but got a pink slip instead.  Thus, they are cynical and trust only themselves; team play is for Boomers.

As Gen X girls came of age, sturdy, clunky shoes became the rage.  Colette Dowling’s 1981 book “The Cinderella Complex” may have inspired them to convey to the world that they had both feet planted firmly on the ground and were not about to depend on a man to take care of them. Sadly, they entered the workforce and encountered the Glass Ceiling.

So, the stage was set for many of these young women to express their cynicism more and more.  It can only be assumed that either directly or indirectly their young daughters subconsciously picked it up.  Within a few years, their friends picked it up.  Now it’s apparently a part of their persona.  I truly hope it’s not too late to snuff out this unfortunate trend.

Comment: Do you have a link to your reference? I'm interested in who first came up with the term.

Answer (score 0):

Vocal fry comed from the realm of singing and coins the raspy sound as a NEGATIVE act as in " oh no you are going to fry your vocal chords"

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?